# CMPedometer warn not counting steps on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios11, core-motion

I have a problem with getting steps on iPad 2017 (iOS 11).

I have this code to check

```
        if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
            startTrackingActivityType() // Works good and I get activity.
        }

        if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {
            // does not work
        } else {
            print("Step Counting Unavailable") // log says that counting is not available here when I debug on iPad

        }
```

Does iPad support steps counting?

I alos set up this key in plist:

```
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) motion use.</string>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to get step counting on ipad?